# IIS Rewrite rule does not work 2nd time onwards - gives 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ohif

We are trying to integrate OHIF with Orthanc Server. and We are using MVC application to integrate.

We have installed IIS and Orthanc Server on the same machine.

We have configured IIS rewrite, where we will rewrite of the response of the Orthanc server.

https://book.orthanc-server.com/faq/iis.html

```
<rules>
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^orthancserver/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:8042/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

All URL Redirect working. And already installed Rewrite Module and I have enabled the proxy too.

I have been chasing unsuccessfully the solution for more than a month. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj9wA.png)

Comment: Enable FRT to learn more about those 404 errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing and you can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From your frt log, it can be seen that the first rewrite is performed through a **ApplicationRequestRoutingHandler**, but the handler for the second rewrite is **system.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler**, so the problem should be in your mvc project , please check the content of url rewriting in your mvc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. This indeed pointed me to the right direction and I was able to fix the issue.